# Can I programatically get hold of the Autos/local variables that is shown when debugging?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, variables, local

Im trying to build an error-logger that loggs running values that is active in the function that caused the error.  (just for fun so its not a critical problem)

When going in break-mode and looking at the locals-tab and autos-tab you can see all active variables (name, type and value), it would be useful to get hold of that for logging purposes when an error occur and on some other occasions.

For my example, I just want to find all local variables that are of type string and integer and store the name and value of them.

Is this possible with reflection? Any tips or pointers that get me closer to my goal would be very appreciated.

I *have* toyed with using expression on a specifik object (a structure) to create an automapper against a dataset, but I have not done anything like what I ask for above, so please make me happy and say its possible.

Thanks.

Comment: @Sinan, thanks for the retagging. But the terms are named "Autos" and "Locals" in visual studio so I think those would be better. "automatic" has nothing to do with my question, so you could take that away. Just my 5 cents.

Comment: you can always roll back any edit. However, "Autos" and "Locals" isn't a "term" - it's the name of a tool window. You may find these terms have no validity outside the context of the Visual Studio Debugger UI.

Comment: @John, I think "Autos" and "Locals" will ring the bell for a lot more people than "automatic" and "local".. But whatever.. The title and the text says it all so I dont care. I just explained why I used those "terms".

Comment: again, you can always roll back the edit. That's how SO is meant to work. I will remind you, however, that tags aren't so much meant to "ring a bell". The purpose of a tag is that some user in the future, looking for similar information, will try searching using a tag. Is it more likely that the user will try searching on "autos" to find your question, or more likely he'll use "automatic"? You decide, and edit accordingly.

Comment: @John, I understand. I for myself think the tags is more to attract people browsing SO-questions, If it is tags they know about, they take a closer look at the question, and if not they ignore it. People who are searching for this issue on google will find it not by the tags, but the content and question title. I will take away the "automatic" tag as it has nothing to do with the quetion and then be a happy coder again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to reproduce the behavior of the debugger, then you may want to *be* a debugger. See the [Visual Studio Extensibility Learning Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx). In particular, see the links under "Debuggers".